# Spring mvc 3 Jqgrid :How to load data to a select Type from a list of objects

Tags: json, hibernate, spring-mvc, jqgrid

I have 2 classes, User.java and Bank.java .
Each User has a reference to a Bank. When I add new user  i must select a bank  from a list of Banks.
So my question is how to load a list of objects(from DB) to a select form in jqGrid, and knowing that this selected data will be registered in the DB as an Integer (the foreign key which refer to the Bank table), can you tell me how this goes.

```
@Entity
public class Utilisateur {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long idUser;
.
    .
@Autowired
@ManyToOne
private Agence agence;

@ManyToOne
private Banque banque;
```

and this is my Controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getall", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody
CustomUserResponse getAll() {

    System.out.println("affichage");

    List<Utilisateur> users = utilisateurDao.getAllUsers();

List<Banque> banks=utilisateurDao.getAllBanks();


    CustomUserResponse response = new CustomUserResponse();
    response.setRows(users);

    response.setRecords(String.valueOf(users.size()));

    response.setPage("1");

    response.setTotal("10");

    return response;
}


    @RequestMapping(value = "/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody
CustomGenericResponse add(

@RequestParam("nom") String nom, @RequestParam("prenom") String prenom,
        @RequestParam("nomAcces") String nomAcces,
        @RequestParam("typeAcces") TypeAcces typeAcces,
        @RequestParam("motPasse") String motPasse,
        @RequestParam("banque") Banque banque

) {

    logger.debug("Received request to add a new user");

    // Construct our new user object. Take note the id is not required.
    // Assign the values from the parameters
    Utilisateur user = new Utilisateur();

    user.setNom(nom);
    user.setPrenom(prenom);
    user.setNomAcces(nomAcces);
    user.setTypeAcces(typeAcces);
    user.setMotPasse(motPasse);
    user.setBanque(banque);
    // Do custom validation here or in your service

    // Call service to add
    Boolean success = utilisateurDao.save(user);
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i find the solution and it work,
to generate the select form, i must insert a valid html (

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/listBanks")
public @ResponseBody
String listBanques(String idbanq) {

    String select = null;
    String selectfinal = null;
    List<Banque> banks = utilisateurDao.getAllBanks();

    for (Banque b : banks) {

        select = select + "<option value=" + b.getIdBanque() + ">"
                + b.getNom() + "</option>"
    }
    selectfinal = "<select>" + select + "</select>";

    return selectfinal;

}
```

and in the ColModel:

```
${name:'idBanque',index:'banque',width:100, editable: true,edittype:"select",editoptions:{dataUrl:"/ConsultationArchive/med/crud/listBanks"}},
```

Thank you for your help, :)

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the documentation on

http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:predefined_formatter

they describe how you can generate a select event that will be used in the edit form.

Ex: (as part of your setup inside the colModel of the bank column

```
formatter:'select', editoptions:{value:"1:One;2:Two"}
```

Where the ID and Names of the banks would be the values you would pass down.  You can also have the grid query your controller to build this list as well.

Comment: Thanks Mark, I tried with this: {name:'banque',index:'banque',width:100, editable: true,formatter "select",edittype:"select",editoptions:{dataUrl:"/ConsultationArchive/med/crud/listBanks"}}, as "/ConsultationArchive/med/crud/listBanks" return a list of banks, It return [Object object] in the colModel and an empty select form in the editform, regards.

Comment: http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:common_rules will show you examples of how each of the 3 methods for building a select list should be constructed.

Comment: Glad I could help, please mark as correct if this led you to a solution.

Comment: Hi, finally i find the solution :)